# What is the VB.net equivalent of this C# command

Tags: vb.net, c#-3.0

```
var safeMode = new SafeMode(other) { WMode = "majority" };
```

I saw this form several time in http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-C%23Driverversionv1.4.x

The `{ WMode = "majority" }` is what I am not familiar with. Is it a code, a collection initializer, or what?

What it does is calling a constructor of SafeMode. I wasn't aware that you can add bracket stuffs after that. Is that a "code" or what?

Comment: In C++ I know that you can put codes on bracket. This is a new notation.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I got great answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is called Object Initializers.

the equivalent vb.net code could be this full code

```
Dim safeMode as New SafeMode(other)
With safeMode
 .WMode = "Majority"
End With
```

or using object initializer syntax.

```
Dim safeMode as New SafeMode(other) With { .WMode = "Majority" }
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/02/05/vb-net-9-0-object-and-array-initializers.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It is called `object` initialization (MSDN - [Overview of Visual Basic 9.0 -  object-initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).

```
Dim objSafeMode = New SafeMode(other) With { .WMode = "majority" }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's part of the C# syntax. Here's a link to a programming guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Example:

```
Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2009/10/14/vb-net-10-collection-initializer.aspx only says that it works only for dictionary and list. I guess there is no equivalent in vb.net